# How to save changes after editing in angular 5/6?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am building an account information page. I want to allow edit and save the changes (ie: name), but i get the same old name back. My code is as follows

```
<div >
    <mat-form-field class="simple-form-field-50" *ngIf="isEditEnable">
      <input matInput placeholder="Name" [(ngModel)]="name">
    </mat-form-field>
    <span *ngIf="!isEditEnable">Name : {{user?.givenName}} </span>
    <button style="border:0;" *ngIf="!isEditEnable" (click)="onEdit()"><span><mat-icon style="font-size:16px;" matSuffix>create</mat-icon></span></button>
    <button *ngIf="isEditEnable" mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="onEdit()">Submit</button>
</div>
```

TS code:

```
export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {
  user: User;

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    ) { }

  isEditEnable = false;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get<User>('/api/user/details', {})
        .subscribe((user) =>  {
          this.user = user;
        });
  }
  onEdit() {
  this.isEditEnable = !this.isEditEnable;
  }
}
```

Code Ouput:

[1] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Rbzz.png)

After clicking edit button:

[2] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7qCr.png)

After clicking submit, it gives old name back without changing

[3] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Rbzz.png)

Comment: can you post your onEdit() function in your TS Code ?

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I have posted it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it looks like you never update the name property on the user, as well as remember to update the user in database (for this you'll need to add an endpoint)

```
<div >
    <mat-form-field class="simple-form-field-50" *ngIf="isEditEnable">
        <input matInput placeholder="Name" [(ngModel)]="name">
    </mat-form-field>
    <span *ngIf="!isEditEnable">Name : {{user?.givenName}} </span>
    <button style="border:0;" *ngIf="!isEditEnable" (click)="onEdit()">
        <span><mat-icon style="font-size:16px;" matSuffix>create</mat-icon></span>
    </button>
    <button *ngIf="isEditEnable" mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="onEdit()">
        Submit
    </button>
</div>

export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {
    user: User;
    name: string;

    constructor(
      private http: HttpClient,
    ) { }

    isEditEnable = false;

    ngOnInit() {
      this.http.get<User>('/api/user/details', {})
          .subscribe((user) =>  {
            this.user = user;
          });
    }

    // assume you have or will add an endpoint to handle user update
    updateUser(user) {
        this.http.put((`/api/user/${this.user.id}`, this.user))
    }

    onEdit() {
        if (this.isEditEnable && this.user.givenName !== this.name) {                
                // assign new name to the user
                this.user.givenName = this.name;
                // use api update the user in your database
                this.updateUser()
        }
        this.isEditEnable = !this.isEditEnable
    }
}
```

The following goes to backend portion (assume you use node with express maybe?)
Your router probably has file that is named `users.js`, there you have a get endpoint defined as following

```
this.router.get('details', someFunctionThatGetsUser);
```

You will need to add another one

```
this.router.put('/:id', functionToUpdateUserInDB);
```

and add a function in your user service that updates it in DB

Comment: awesome :) do you mind to accept the other answer  too? :) (I know I posted it later..) [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53938176/how-to-make-icon-work-similar-to-button-in-angular-5-6/53938558#53938558]

Comment: Hi @Uma, my question is satisfied but how to reflect it in database? i used post method changes are shown but not in database. Do you mind clearing it? BTW yes i will accept for previous question>

Comment: ok, I will need to see a little bit more of your code. Show me the content of your router for user, as well as the function that `get` calls in order to get the user